Complex Pass & Fail Formula based on AQL chart
I'm working on a garments division and we need to perform a lot of defect analysis and therefore, I need to put huge number of data to analyze it. I'm looking for a solution to pass & fail formula. We have AQL, which is mentioned below-
[AQC chart 1.5]
So, in AQL 1.5 for sample quantity 50pcs of garments, acceptable defect would be 2, if found 3 it will consider as "Fail". I'll have defect number which could be from 0 to 20pcs or so. Like I said, if we found 3pcs of defect where the acceptable defect quantity is 2 in 50pcs of sample quantity, it will consider as "Fail" if we have 2 or 1 or even have zero defect it will consider as "Pass". Like this, for AQL sample quantity 80, acceptable range is 3. If found 4 or more it will consider as "Fail". I'm totally new in the excel. I had some time with excel but I can't pull it together. Do you have any idea how to do it?
As this is pretty complex, I couldn't gather anything. I tried with basic but I can't work with 2 or more relations within the formula/function. I want to learn how it could be done.

You need VLOOKUP against a sorted table, where the last parameter is set to TRUE. This gives you the fail mark for a quantity.

Can you show how it can be done? I am not able to use VLOOPUP to this extent. However, I am understanding the basic. But can't work with this one.

I got a simple formula and it works perfectly. Here it is:
=IF(AND(A1=5,B1>0),"Fail",IF(AND(A1=8,B1>0),"Fail",IF(AND(A1=13,B1>0),"Fail",IF(AND(A1=20,B1>1),"Fail",IF(AND(A1=20,B1>1),"Fail",IF(AND(A1=32,B1>1),"Fail",IF(AND(A1=50,B1>2),"Fail",IF(AND(A1=80,B1>3),"Fail",IF(AND(A1=125,B1>5),"Fail",IF(AND(A1=200,B1>7),"Fail",IF(AND(A1=315,B1>10),"Fail","Pass")))))))))))

Though it has lot of codes to work with. I assume VLOOKUP would be best to call the AQL chart as it has more variations.


for yourself job, - for algorithm. The formula is =IFS(AND(G2<=$B$2;F2>0);"Pass";AND(G2<=$B$3;F2>$A$2);"Pass";AND(G2<=$B$4;F2>$A$3);"Pass";AND(G2<=$B$4;F2>$A$4);"Pass";TRUE;"Fail")


Here is the solution (Excel-365):

[H2] =IF(G2<=XLOOKUP(F2,$A$2:$A$5,$B$2:$B$5,,1),"Pass","Fail")

Due to the technical reason, you need to add one more row to the AQL chart as depicted above.
F2:G15 is the range with test data. To work, you need to use F2 and G2 only.
For Excel prior to 365:

=IF(G2<=VLOOKUP(F2,$A$8:$B$11,2,TRUE),"Pass","Fail")

The modified AQL table should be used:



AQL 1.5
Accept




0
2


51
3


81
5


126
5




It returns with an error "#NAME?". I have done exactly like you shown but doesn't work, Rotabor.

You Excel version is below 365. Please use the corresponding variant from the modified answer.
